# Kinect camera not found with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installed Ubuntu 12 and Fuerte first and couldn't get the Kinect camera to show up. Reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 and Electric and stepped line by line through installation guide and installed it by using sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect.

When I tried to 'rosrun openni_launch openni.launch' I got permission errors from usblib (can't remember the exact error). Found the 55-primesense-usb.rules file and the permissions looked ok.

Tried to then install all the OpenNI drivers directly from the website http://www.pansenti.com/wordpress/?page_id=1740 and now when I run 'rosrun openni...' I get this error. After running through all those steps when I run the example I get this.
/x86-Release$ sudo ./Sample-Players
503 INFO       New log started on 2012-06-11 19:15:24
636 INFO       OpenNI version is 1.5.2 (Build 23)-Linux-x86 (Dec 28 2011 17:53:48)
680 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: UNKNOWN
One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

I'm doing everything by the book and nothing is working. Any suggestions? I've been trying for 4 hours to get this camera working and am at my wits end.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36271/kinect-camera-not-found-with-ros/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35745/openni_launch-failure-cannot-launch-node-of-type/#35831).

Hope it helps.

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0